# Python href and save to .txt (no worries, not another regex question)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

I currently am working on creating a python script that allows a user to input a torrent's hash (via terminal), and checks for more trackers via a website. However, I am at a loss and was hoping to receive some advice since I'm new to Python programming. I'm running into trouble since my result from html_page has another link to go to. So, my program assigns html_page "http://torrentz.eu/*************** but, now I find myself trying to get it to follow another link on the page to arrive at http://torrentz.eu/announcelist_***** ... that being said, I have found it can be retrieved (as it would appear from viewing the source)

```
    <a href="/announcelist_********" rel="e">&#181;Torrent compatible list here</a>
```

or possibly retrieved from here since values are same as they appear in /announcelist_****

```
    <a name="post-comment"></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="torrent" value="******" />
```

Since the /announcelist_**** appears in text format I was also wondering how I might be able to save the resulting tracker list in a .txt file. That being said, this is my progress as of now on the Python scripting.

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib2
    import re
    var = raw_input("Enter hash:")
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://torrentz.eu/" +var)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            print link.get('href')
```

I'd also like to thank all of y'all in advance for your support, knowledge, advice, and skills.

Edit: I've altered the code to appear as follows:

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib2
    import re
    hsh = raw_input("Enter Hash:")
    html_data = urllib2.urlopen("http://torrentz.eu/" +hsh, 'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
    announce = soup.find('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/announcelist")})
    print announce
```

Which results in:

```
    <a href="/announcelist_00000" rel="e">&#181;Torrent compatible list here</a>
```

So, now I'm just looking for a way to get the **/announcelist_00000** portion of output only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but you should be able to open the remote file and a local file, read the contents from one and write them to the other and save. Does that help?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve, but honestly I'm new to python and really am somewhat at a loss for how I would go about doing... but yes, I would like to be able to: #1) input hash manually (through a console prompt) #2) have http://torrentz.eu concatenated with hash to achieve URL of http://torrentz.eu/hashoftorrent #3) find and follow link to http://torrentz.eu/announcelist_***** (stars represent value associated with tracker) #4) save page http://torrentz.eu/announcelist_***** to /home/durr/trackers.txt

Comment: I have to post this as an answer. Too much code to post as a comment

Answer (score 1):

Once you have opened the url, you are able to find the `href` as you point out. Now, open that `href` using `urlopen`. When you encounter the file that you want to copy over, open it like so:

```
remote_file = open(filepath)
locale_file = open(path_to_local_file, 'w')

local_file.write(remote_file.read())
local_file.close()
remote_file.close()
```

Here's how you should probably go about doing this:

```
# insert code that you've already written
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
    remote_file = open(link.get('href'))
    local_file = open(path_too_local_file, 'w')
    local_file.write(remote_file.read())
    local_file.close()
    remote_file.close()
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work.

Hope this helps

Comment: What should the full coding for the full program look like? I'm still a bit too green to understand how to put the whole thing together I guess.

Comment: @durr88: I can do it, but not right now. I will put up what I can soon, though

Comment: I have added some code that I think will work, but I haven't tested it yet (I can only do that next week). Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is the value of the href attribute, then
see what you get if you add the line:

```
print announce['href']
```